# Managing libraries hosted on EmacsWiki

Tags: package, emacs-wiki

I recently learned that some former MELPA libraries are now  available only from the EmacsWiki.

Let aside security implications,

Is there an equivalent of `M-x package-list-packages` for those libraries?
Is there an equivalent of `(use-package foo)`, which I could put in my init file?
Any best practice suggested to deal with EmacsWiki libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent of `M-x package-list-packages` for those libraries?

The [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) package manager supports installation from the EmacsWiki; after doing `M-x el-get-emacswiki-build-local-recipes`, `M-x el-get-list-packages` will show packages from EmacsWiki as well.

> Is there an equivalent of `(use-package foo)`, which I could put in my init file?

`(el-get-bundle foo)` would be approximately equivalent.

Comment: +1. Good to know. I didn't realize that el-get works with Emacs-Wiki libraries also.

Comment: I tried to add to my init `(use-package el-get :config (el-get-emacswiki-build-local-recipes)) (el-get-bundle dired+)`. However, `el-get-bundle` raises an error, when generating autoloads and byte-compiling the autoload file, because dired-omit-files is void. A hack would be to `(setq dired-omit-files nil)`, but clearly there should be a proper way.

Comment: @antonio oh, you have to load el-get before using `el-get-bundle` (because it's a macro), you can't start using it in the same statement that you load it. Maybe try `(el-get nil 'dired+)` instead. And `el-get-emacswiki-build-local-recipes` takes a long time, you probably don't want to run it every time you startup.

Comment: As regards `(el-get-emacswiki-build-local-recipes)`, `use-package :config` is clever enough to run it only the first time.
Still `(el-get nil 'dired+)` gives `error in process sentinel: Symbol’s value as variable is void: dired-omit-files`. The mentioned variable is part part of dired (not dired+), which is not loaded by `el-get`. Byte-compiling `dired+` works, so the problem is in the way `el-get` installs `dired+`.

Comment: @antonio oh, I misread the error in your first comment. I think it's due to `dired+` misusing `;;;###autoload`. You can work around it with `(add-to-list 'el-get-sources '(:name dired+ :autoloads nil))` before the `(el-get nil 'dired+)` call, or using `el-get-bundle`: `(el-get-bundle dired+ :autoloads nil)`.

Comment: Thx. I've updated [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el). No need for a workaround with the update. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Drew: confirm everything's working. Question closed

Answer (score 1):

1. No. As far as I know, there is no equivalent of `package-list-packages` or `use-package` for libraries uploaded to the Emacs Wiki [Elisp Area](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=elisp-area;context=0). In general, you download the file(s) for a library to a local directory that is in your `load-path`, and then `require` the library feature name or main-file name (e.g. `(require 'isearch+)`.
2. Questions about things such as best practice are off-topic on emacs.SE, as they are generally primarily opinion-based or too broad. Questions here should be specific and call for specific answers.
3. Anyone can upload code to Emacs Wiki. As a result, the code there is variable in what it does, how it does it, and perhaps how well it does it. As is true in general elsewhere, it's a good idea to take a look at code you download before using it, and preferably take a look at any associated doc there may be for it.

Comment: Please consider moving your comment to @npostavs's answer about elget. My answer only speaks about downloading libraries to a local directory that you add to your `load-path`, and then `require`-ing those libraries. Doing that, I think you will encounter no such problem.

Comment: Hey, @Drew, as you are the author of by far the largest number of useful libraries on EmacsWiki (thank you!), can you explain why you choose that as your publishing mechanism?

Comment: @PhilHudson: Laziness. See https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7vocqa/update_on_melpa_removing_emacswiki_packages_they/dtuhzmt/.