# fetching elisp library from url

Tags: use-package, el-get

I am using `use-package` in my .emacs and it is great. However
occasionally I want to use a 3-rd party code which is not in [M]ELPA.
Of course, I can download it but then I will need to maintain a copy of it on all the machines I use. Now I can just copy .emacs to a new machine, start emacs and it will download and install all packages. I wonder if there is anything similar for non-packaged libraries? Something which will fetch them via HTTP or git, compile and add to load path.

Here is an example of a package I want to use:

https://github.com/emacsmirror/emacswiki.org/blob/master/zoom-frm.el

I suspect that maybe `el-get` can do this but I am unsure. Maybe somebody can show me an example for this `zoom-ftm.el`?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean [`zoom-frm.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el)?

Comment: Dunno whether this is what you're asking, but I think this example, for downloading and compiling the [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) files from Emacs Wiki, might be relevant (i.e., might help): https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BulkDownloadCompileLoad

Comment: @Drew, yes that zoom-frm. Thanks for the download snippet. It looks like what I want. I was hoping somebody automated this as a library. For example, a function where I can pass a URL, list of files and the package name. It could be generalized further by supporting git checkouts in addition to HTTP downloads.

Comment: Found this related question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50815/managing-libraries-hosted-on-emacswiki

Comment: Please add the link in your last comment to your answer too, for future reference. (Comments can be deleted at any time.) Thx.

Comment: Do you maybe want to change the title of your question? It refers to fetching from git, but the example in your question and answer is fetching from Emacs Wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any existing solution to do that and come up with my own:

```
;; Inspired by https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BulkDownloadCompileLoad 
(defun fetch-and-load-elisp (pkg-name pkg-files base-url base-dir)
  (let ((pkg-dir (concat (file-name-as-directory base-dir) (symbol-name pkg-name))))
    (require 'url)
    (add-to-list 'load-path pkg-dir)
    (make-directory pkg-dir t)
    (mapcar (lambda (arg)
              (let ((local-file (concat (file-name-as-directory pkg-dir) arg)))
                (unless (file-exists-p local-file)
                  (url-copy-file (concat base-url arg) local-file t))))
            pkg-files)
    (byte-recompile-directory pkg-dir 0)
    (require pkg-name)))

(when (fetch-and-load-elisp 'zoom-frm '("frame-cmds.el" "frame-fns.el" "zoom-frm.el") "https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/" "~/lisp/")
      (define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?+)] 'zoom-in/out)
      (define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?-)] 'zoom-in/out)
      (define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?=)] 'zoom-in/out)
      (define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?0)] 'zoom-in/out))
```

I am not proficient in ELISP, and perhaps it could be improved. Error handling comes to mind. Also, the byte compilation is now run every time, even when files were unchanged.

Comment: I think you meant `when` rather than `if` in the last expression. Or else you need a `progn` around the `define-key` calls.